# matrix of parity check of code

Tags: matrices

$$H=\begin{vmatrix} 1& 1& 0 &1& 0 &0\\
      1& 0 &1& 0& 1& 0\\
      1 &1 &1& 0& 0 &1\end{vmatrix}$$

1. Determine the generator matrix $G$ of this code.
2. Find 2 coded words that begin by $101$, $110$.
3. We suppose we receive word is $111101$. Decode this received word by identifying and correcting the erroneous bits.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you consider a binary linear code. The $3\times 6$ matrix $H$ has the form $(A\mid I_3)$ where $I_3$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. Then $G= (I_3\mid A^t)$ is a generator matrix, since $GH^t = 0$.